# How to get field values by alias, not by name in JSF?

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I've met with one problem: when I make SQL request to a database with aliases to field names I cannot display them with h:dataTable (I use JSF).

Here the example. The request:

```
SELECT 
    computers.name AS computers_name,
FROM
    computers
WHERE
    computers.id IS NOT NULL AND (computers.group_id=1);
```

And the XHTML code:

```
            <h:dataTable value="#{advancedSearchComp.computers}"  
                    var="computer" rowClasses="oddTableRow, evenTableRow"
                    headerClass="tableHeader" styleClass="table">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">name</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_name}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

And there is a problem in that because h:column cannot get field value by alias, only by real name, and it returns null.

What is the best solution for that?

I'd be grateful for any hint.

UPDATE. All known to me manuals only consider trivial cases "SELECT * FROM table".

Is there a common way to display ResultSet in JSF without tricky methods?

UPDATE. I did it:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{advancedSearchComp.selectedComputers}" var="computer" rowClasses="oddTableRow, evenTableRow"
                         headerClass="tableHeader" styleClass="table">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">id</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_id}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="name">Name</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_name}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Location</f:facet>
                    #{computer.locations_name}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Rack</f:facet>
                    #{computer.racks_name}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Rack unit</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_rack_unit}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Serial</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_serial}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Inv number</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_inv_number}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                    #{computer.computers_status_name}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

public List<ComputerWrapper> getSelectedComputers() throws SQLException{
    ComputerWrapper computer;
    selectedComputers.clear();
    if (query==null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        Statement sth=dbhIrmdb.createStatement();
        ResultSet rowSet=sth.executeQuery(query);
        while (rowSet.next()) {
            computer=new ComputerWrapper();
            computer.setComputers_id(rowSet.getString("computers_id"));
            computer.setComputers_name(rowSet.getString("computers_name"));
            computer.setLocations_name(rowSet.getString("locations_name"));
            computer.setRacks_name(rowSet.getString("racks_name"));
            computer.setComputers_rack_unit(rowSet.getString("computers_rack_unit"));
            computer.setComputers_serial(rowSet.getString("computers_serial"));
            computer.setComputers_inv_number(rowSet.getString("computers_inv_number"));
              computer.setComputers_status_name(rowSet.getString("computers_status_name"));
            selectedComputers.add(computer);
        }         
        sth.close();
        return selectedComputers;
    }
```

//        return null;
    }

public class ComputerWrapper {
    private String computers_id, computers_name, locations_name, racks_name, computers_rack_unit,
            computers_serial, computers_inv_number, computers_status_name;

```
public String getComputers_id() {
    return computers_id;
}

public void setComputers_id(String computers_id) {
    this.computers_id=computers_id;
}

public String getComputers_name() {
    return computers_name;
}

public void setComputers_name(String computers_name) {
    this.computers_name=computers_name;
}

public String getLocations_name() {
    return locations_name;
}

public void setLocations_name(String locations_name) {
    this.locations_name=locations_name;
}

public String getRacks_name() {
    return racks_name;
}

public void setRacks_name(String racks_name) {
    this.racks_name=racks_name;
}

public String getComputers_rack_unit() {
    return computers_rack_unit;
}

public void setComputers_rack_unit(String computers_rack_unit) {
    this.computers_rack_unit=computers_rack_unit;
}

public String getComputers_serial() {
    return computers_serial;
}

public void setComputers_serial(String computers_serial) {
    this.computers_serial=computers_serial;
}

public String getComputers_inv_number() {
    return computers_inv_number;
}

public void setComputers_inv_number(String computers_inv_number) {
    this.computers_inv_number=computers_inv_number;
}

public String getComputers_status_name() {
    return computers_status_name;
}

public void setComputers_status_name(String computers_status_name) {
    this.computers_status_name=computers_status_name;
}

public ComputerWrapper() {
    computers_id=""; computers_name=""; locations_name=""; racks_name=""; computers_rack_unit="";
    computers_serial=""; computers_inv_number=""; computers_status_name="";
}
```

Comment: What is the `computers` attribute in `advancedSearchComp` managed bean ?

Comment: Yes, it's the JavaBean accessor returning ResultSet.

Comment: How are you binding the results of your query to the view i.e. how do you execute the query, from a `@ManagedBean` or using JSTL `<sql:query>`? This looks really strange. Also, which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: I execute the query in a Managed Bean, the function returns ResultSet. Also I use JSF 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class `Computer`

```
public class Computer{
    private String computerName;
    // getter-setter
}
```

`advancedSearchComp` managed bean

```
@ManagedBean (name = "advancedSearchComp")
public class AdvancedSearchComp{
    private List<Computer> computers;
    // getter-setter
    // code to populate computers and map result set to the Computer bean
}
```

To map the result set to the java bean, you need to iterate over the result set and prepare a list.

Then in the XHTML

```
<h:dataTable value="#{advancedSearchComp.computers}"  
    var="computer" rowClasses="oddTableRow, evenTableRow"
    headerClass="tableHeader" styleClass="table">
    <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">name</f:facet>
          <h:outputText value = "#{computer.computerName}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**Update:**
If you want to display 16 or a large number of fields, you have below two options:

**Option1** Add all the fields in the bean and then display them as above

**Option2** Add a map in the bean and then use this map in the XHTML.

```
public class Computer{
    private Map<String, Object> dataMap;
    // getter-setter
}
```

And on XHTML

```
<h:dataTable value="#{advancedSearchComp.computers}"  
    var="computer" rowClasses="oddTableRow, evenTableRow"
    headerClass="tableHeader" styleClass="table">
    <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">name</f:facet>
          <h:outputText value = "#{computer.dataMap['computerName']}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Brand</f:facet>
          <h:outputText value = "#{computer.dataMap['computerBrand']}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Iterating over resultset to fill dataMap

```
ResultSet rs= statement.executeQuery();
if(rs!= null){
dataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while(rs.next()){
    for(int _iterator = 0; _iterator < rsmd.getColumnCount(); _iterator++){
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(_iterator + 1);
    Object columnValue = rs.getObject(_iterator + 1);
        dataMap.put(columnName , columnValue );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I took it into consideration. But I have to display 16 fields so it's not a fancy decision. I'd have to create 16 fields.

Comment: If you want to display 16 fields, yes you can create 16 fields in the Computer class
OR
You can create a map to hold key-value (fieldname - fieldvalue) and then display this map in the datatable

Comment: I think about overriding ResultSet class to be able to address fields by aliases instead real column names.

Comment: I'd try Option 2 with HashMap<String, List<String>>

Comment: I did as you said. The cells in h:dataTable are empty again and it looks like the same problem.

Comment: h:inputTextarea gets everything from #{computer.dataMap['computerName']}

Comment: Can you share the code that you are trying Check if the data is being correctly mapped from result set to the list of bean. I think you would need `Map<String, Object> dataMap` and not `Map<String, List<String>> dataMap`.

Comment: Code horror: <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">computers_serial</f:facet>
                        #{advancedSearchComp.weirdColumns.get('computers_serial')}
                    </h:column>

Comment: private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> weirdColumns=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

Comment: How should I fill private Map<String, Object> dataMap ?

Comment: I appreciate you patience. The same result. The rows count is equal to proper result, only the cells are empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get it via alias. You'll have to assign it to an actual object somewhere in the bean. If you haven't created an object tailored to store results from the ResultSet yet, do so, pass it to your page and display.

It also helps to wrap your name around an outputText tag, like

```
<h:outputText value="#{computer.computersName}" />
```

Comment: That's so weird. ResultSet.getString() works perfectly with column aliases.

Comment: Snap! You found that out while I was writing my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `computers` attribute in `advancedSearchComp` is of type `ResultSet`, then you should be able to write something like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{advancedSearchComp.computers}" var="computer">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">name</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{computer.getString('computers_name')}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: It's strange. <h:outputText value="#{computer.getString(1)}" /> is not working.

Comment: Nope, the table just disappears.